# socle and essential extension of finitely generated mod over an artin algebra

Tags: representation-theory, finitely-generated, injective-module, artinian, socle

In page 40 of Auslander‘s *representation theory of artin algebra*, the proposition 4.1,

> For $A$ in mod$\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is an artin algebra we have the following.
>
> a) $A=0$ iff $socA=0$
>
> b) A is an essential extension of $socA$.
>
> c) $A\to I$ is n injective envelope of A iff the induced morphism $socA\to I$ is an injective envelope.
>
> d) An injective module I in mod$\Lambda$ is indecomposable iff $socA$ is simple

In the proof of this proposition it is stated that (b),(c) and (d) are easily verified consequences of (a).

But I am confused in using (a) to prove them

Comment: Which one do you have trouble with? For example, to prove b), if not, there is a non-zero submodule  $M$ of $A$ with $M\cap \mathrm{soc}\, A=0$. But this says $\mathrm{soc}\, M=M\cap\mathrm{soc}\, A=0$ and thus from a), $M=0$.

Comment: @Mohan thanks for your patient answer. Maybe I didn’t understand the socle of a module very well......I’ll rethink about b c and d